# How to create reflection effect for TextView in android

Tags: android, textview

I have got a tech problem of implementing the reflection effect for TextView, in order to create a Clock/Timer. I have read many articles about this, but they are all about adding reflection effect for Images.

Would anyone please point me to the right direction to do so or simply show me some demo which are already there.

one of the articles I have read is [here](http://www.jappit.com/blog/2009/01/25/j2me-images-how-to-create-a-reflection-effect/). Others are basically the same.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi Harry, can you please add the code to how to make this reflection effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the view to a bitmap image as explained [here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/30676.aspx).

Once you have a bitmap,flip it, add a gradient mask,
and blur it a little to give a little more natural look to the
reflection.