# Steps for create a reflection of a text or image in android application

Tags: android, reflection

i am a beginner to android application development.. and with curiosity towards app development i wonder to know the step by step process of creating a reflection to an TEXT or image in android application. please help me with the code

thank you.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644501/display-replica-image-with-mirror-image-in-android/13644554#13644554

Comment: @G_S But where do i have to put this code.?? do i have to call this call..?? do i have to just keep the image in my resource folder.??
and how to get mirror effect of a text.? does it contain the same procedure..?? sir please help me out with this.!

Comment: Yes you have to make a call to this method . And coming to the image, Its your requirement. If you put it in the resource you need to get the bitmap of the image using bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage); and pass it to the method.
And for the text am not sure but you may get it using textviewOjg.getDrawingCache() and send the obtained bitmap to the same function (have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064234/how-to-create-reflection-effect-for-textview-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom view for this and override onDraw().  Something like this should work to reflect:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postTranslate(width, 0);
    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
    matrix.postRotate(180, width / 2, height / 2);
    canvas.concat(matrix);

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.restore();
}
```